# Why does wifi drop out constantly?

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, network-manager

With any version of Ubuntu I try it seems that I have an issue with wifi.

Try as I might, I cannot make the wifi stay connected. I have since installed iwScanner and I can see that my wifi network is on a different channel to the others in range. I can also see a signal strength of about -60 consistently except every minute or so (sometimes as often as 10seconds apart) it drops to -100 or essentially nothing.

If I boot the same machine into Windows 7 it seems to work okay, other laptops seem to work okay.

It is a Linksys WUSB54GC v.3 which seems according to the community docs to be supported. I am not really that far away from the router and besides my mobile phone connects to the wifi network fine from the same distance.

The router is getting old so I had considered maybe it was a problem with the router (Draytek) but then I should have issues with the other machines.

Network is not broadcasting its SSID and is using WPA2

*Edit*

Also the dropouts to -100 signal are much more frequent when I try to connect to the network using network manager. Every ~2 seconds consistently.

Comment: At my university I've got the same problem with the encrypted network, even though it uses the same routers as the public WiFi. About every 10 minutes my connection gets dropped. The public WiFi in combination with VPN works flawlessly. I'd too would be interested in a solution.

Comment: I have exactly @Georg's problem (My current solution is unplug a eth0 cable from a nearby PC...)

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Phil: 10.10, the time to deconnection varies quite a bit. (was just online for 30 minutes before I got deconnected) Usually it's much worse when many people are using the internet.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a similar problem that was caused by the fact that my laptop scanned for N networks about every minute or so. That dropped the link to my router that did not support N network. I switched to another routher with N support and did not see the problem anymore. Could you have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend you to try to change the encryption of your router to WPA, and even WEP if necessary. Some drivers have had problems with WPA/WPA2 encryption. Also, it could be realted to overheating. I had a Lenovo Thinkpad with an Intel Wifi card that every now and then would drop its connection. After much testing I discovered it was dropping packets when the card was hot. The same happens to a PCMCIA card I still have.

Good Luck

Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

As [I answered before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9014/auto-connect-to-hidden-wireless-without-elevating-privelege/9059#9059), don't hide your SSID. It was not meant to be used that way, it is not a security feature, and it may well be the only cause to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but then I had a very simple answer. I changed my WiFi settings so that I had to manually connect to WiFi; It no longer connected automatically.Then I restarted my laptop, and it all worked. However, If this continues to be an issue for you, and you can't find a good solution, I would either see if it gets fixed in the next OS update, or contact the GNOME e-mail help center. Best of luck, amigo!