# Automatically connect to a hidden wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, automation

Ubuntu 19.10 doesn't automatically connect to saved hidden wireless networks. I have each time to go to Settings → *Wi-Fi* → <kbd>⋮</kbd> (3 dots menu on the top right) → *Connect to Hidden Network* to get connected to Wi-Fi.

Is there a way to make Ubuntu connect to a saved, available hidden network automatically in the same way as visible networks?

Comment: My version of Ubuntu is 19.10

Comment: Is "Connect Automatically" enabled in the wi-fi connection profile?

Comment: Yes, it is. I even upgraded to 20.04 LTS and I still have the same issue.

Comment: From the help pages... "You may have to check the settings of the wireless access point or router to see what the network name is. If you don’t have the network name (SSID), you can use the BSSID (Basic Service Set Identifier, the access point’s MAC address), which looks something like 02:00:01:02:03:04 and can usually be found on the underside of the access point.". So, try using the BSSID instead of the SSID. Use `nm-connection-editor`.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/9014/auto-connect-to-hidden-wireless-without-elevating-privilege

Comment: Also see https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-auto-connect-to-hidden-network-xfce/70447/4

Comment: Google "ubuntu automatically connect to hidden network"

Answer (score 3):

For me like @heynnema said using the BSSID worked for me.

I used the following click path to change the BSSID:

- on the right top corner, the down right arrow
- Then onto WiFi
- Wireless network settings
- Connect to hidden radio networks
- entered / selected the hidden radio network
- then on the gear in the row of the hidden network
- onto identity
- and there is a dropdown for BSSID

If you have an access point that has multiple GHz channels, you can also have multiple BSSIDs here. Depending on what you select, the corresponding channel is used.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred to me when I reused the earlier connection to connect to a now-hidden Wi-Fi network on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

To fix it, I **forget** that profile and create a new one from Settings → *Wi-Fi*  → <kbd>⋮</kbd> (3 dots menu on the top right) → *Connect to Hidden Network* → *New...* (in the connection drop-down).

Now it's automatically connected to that hidden network.